# How to check a xib's file owner programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, xib

I'm in the xib's implementation - 
is it possible to check who's the file's owner programmatically during runtime?

something like this: (just it doesn't work obviously :P)

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    if ([self.owner isEqualToString:@"FirstTab"]){
        //do something
    }else if ([self.owner isEqualToString:@"SecondTab"]){
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: What class does the `initWithCode:`-method belong to? Owner or NSView/UIView?

Answer (score 1):

From the `UIViewController`, you should be able to get the name of the nib file like this, from within  `viewDidLoad`:

`self.nibName`

You can check the nib name the same way you did above:

```
if ([self.nibName isEqualToString:@"FirstTab"]) {

} else if ([self.nibName isEqualToString:@"SecondTab"]) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's your custom `NSView`-subclass, add property with your owner

```
@interface MyCustomView : NSView 

@property (nonatomic, weak) id owner;

@end
```

Don't forget to set this property in your `NSViewController` like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if ([self.view isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]])
  {
    MyCustomView *view = (MyCustomView *)self.view;
    view.owner = self; // in view's awakeFromNib: check owner value
  }
}
```

I usually define protocols, but it depends on your purposes. Why do you need to know if the view has owner object?